# Test my json data parser should return a logger

Tags: c#, unit-testing, moq, xunit

Let's look at my json string structure.

[image: loggers]

So there are 7 loggers, let's expand the nodes for the details.

```
{
"root_logger" : "MyFailoverLogger",
"loggers": [
    {
        "logger_name": "MyFileLogger",
        "logger_type": "MyCompany.Loggers.FileSystemLogger",
        "layout": "${message}|${exception}",
        "stack_trace": {
            "error": true,
            "fatal": false
        },
        "file_path_pattern" : "\\\\corporate.MyCompany.com\\data\\recordings\\logs\\YYYY\\MM\\DD",
        "file_name_pattern" : "app.{MMDDhhmm}.log",
        "rollover_after_n_hours" : 5,
        "rollover_after_n_megabytes": 5,
        "level" : {
            "min_level" : "INFO",
            "max_level" : "DEBUG"
        }
    },
    {
        "logger_name" : "MyDbLogger",
        "logger_type" : "MyCompany.Loggers.DatabaseLogger",
        "connection_string" : "",
        "target_table" : "",
        "command_timeout_milliseconds" : 100,
        "layout" : "${message}",
        "level" : {
            "min_level" : "INFO",
            "max_level" : "DEBUG"
        }
    },
```

I am not sure how to test it but I have the primary code here.

```
 [Theory]
    [InlineData("MyFileLogger")]
    [InlineData("MyDbLogger")]
    [InlineData("MyDbLogger2")]
    [InlineData("MyConsoleLogger")]
    [InlineData("MyNullLogger")]
    [InlineData("MyMultiplexingLogger")]
    [InlineData("MyFailoverLogger")]
    public void JSONConfigurationFileParser_Should_Return_A_Logger_Given_A_Name(string expextedLoggerName)
    {
        // ARRANGE
        var currentFilePath = Environment.CurrentDirectory + @"\MyCompanyConfiguration.json";
        var jsonString = File.ReadAllText(currentFilePath);
        var jsonConfigurationFileParser = new JSONConfigurationFileParser(jsonString);

        // ACT
        var actualLoggers = jsonConfigurationFileParser.DeserializeLogger();// It is a collection.

        // ASSERT
    }
```

The `actualLoggers` does return all 7 loggers. My question is that I am not sure how to test it properly. Should I use `InlineData` or something else? I left the assert part empty now. By the way, using Moq is okay.

Comment: What is your test trying to accomplish?  If it is the existence of the expected logger, then some kind of contains test would be appropriate.

Comment: @SteveMitcham, I thought it but there will be many `Contains`. Should I pass the long json string as expected? Like [this](http://jsonassert.skyscreamer.org/)?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Since the InlineData parameter will call the test once for each of the attributes.  You just need to add a search in the deserialized object to find the particular node you are expecting to see.

Since you don't show what your deserialized format is, I will just guess in the example.

```
[Theory]
[InlineData("MyFileLogger")]
[InlineData("MyDbLogger")]
[InlineData("MyDbLogger2")]
[InlineData("MyConsoleLogger")]
[InlineData("MyNullLogger")]
[InlineData("MyMultiplexingLogger")]
[InlineData("MyFailoverLogger")]
public void JSONConfigurationFileParser_Should_Return_A_Logger_Given_A_Name(string expectedLoggerName)
    {
        // ARRANGE
        var currentFilePath = Environment.CurrentDirectory + @"\MyCompanyConfiguration.json";
        var jsonString = File.ReadAllText(currentFilePath);
        var jsonConfigurationFileParser = new JSONConfigurationFileParser(jsonString);

        // ACT
        var actualLoggers = jsonConfigurationFileParser.DeserializeLogger();

        // ASSERT
        Assert.True(actualLoggers.Any(x=> x.Name == expectedLoggerName));
    }
```

At this point you need to decide whether this is a generic test that is testing the parser, in which case throwing a few different configuration files at the parser and writing specific tests for those scenarios (i.e. badly formed file, single logger, multiple loggers, etc.)  These tests should prove that the parser is working correctly.

A test case like yours specific to show that each logger was parsed, plus perhaps one additional test without the InlineData parameters to show that the correct number of total nodes were parsed would be good.

Comment: `actualLoggers ` is a collection, which has 7 loggers. Say `actualLoggers.ToList()[0]` is for  `"MyFileLogger"` etc. Is there a better way to do it? I even think using propertydata, each object contains each logger. So any idea?

Comment: It comes down to what you are trying to accomplish with this unit test. Are you testing your configuration file, or the JSON parser?

Comment: I would say perhaps both.

Comment: As I said in my answer, those would be different tests.  To test the parser, pass in specific strings and don't involve the file.  To test the file, you would then decide what you want to check, is order important, then use the indexing to make sure the loggers are in the right place.  If it just the properties, then check all the properties on the logger that you are loading.  Unit testing takes practice, and all the nuances go way beyond what we can answer here.

Comment: Wait a minute. I marked the answer. But does Assert have `IsTrue` in `XUNIT`. It failed the compilation.

Comment: I'll look it up and correct the answer.  I normally use nunit.